# Trouble with download of cordova ; Wrong npm version

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, npm

I am trying to download apache cordova using node.js, however when I do this I get the following warnings and the process stops and does not make the connections necessary to complete the download of all the files. This is the entire output from my Mac command line when I try to do this download:

```
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree /usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@5.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── q@1.0.1
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@5.0.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.1.0, rc@0.5.2, shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, d8@0.4.4, init-package-json@1.5.0, elementtree@0.1.5, request@2.47.0, glob@4.0.6, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.3, tar@1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@3.9.0, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, npm@1.3.4).
```

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I had the same problems. I solved it this way:

- Delete your node installation.
- Download an install the latest 10.9 version of node: [Archived

  Downloads of node.js](http://nodejs.org/dist/)